# Creating a synonym for all objects in another schema

Tags: oracle

**I am interested in creating a SYNONYM for another schema** and all objects in them (Tables, View, Procedures, Packages, etc).  Currently users are getting an error that a certain table doesn't exist.  It's happening because they are running a query like **SELECT * FROM mytable**.  If the query were **SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable** it would work.

Does creating public synonym make the schema available to all users or roles?  Are there any security issues with granting a public synonym?  Should I use a non-public synonym?  **We are allocating permissions to the schema via roles.**

Is there a query or script that would enable this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you probably want a public synonym. From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-SYNONYM.html#GUID-A806C82F-1171-478E-A910-F9C6C42739B2):

> Specify PUBLIC to create a public synonym. Public synonyms are
> accessible to all users. However each user must have appropriate
> privileges on the underlying object in order to use the synonym.

I think the main security issue they mention is to not create a public synonym with the same name as an existing schema.

See also [object name resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561).

There's not a simple command, but you could script it with something like this:

```
begin
  for r in (select owner, table_name from all_tables where owner = 'MYSCHEMA')
  loop
    execute immediate 'create public synonym ' || r.table_name || ' for ' || r.owner || '.' || r.table_name;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Edit: if you want more than just tables, you can change the query to loop over all_objects instead and pick the object types you want:

```
begin
  for r in (select owner, object_name from all_objects
            where owner = 'MYSCHEMA' 
            and object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW','PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE'))
  loop
    execute immediate 'create public synonym ' || r.object_name 
        || ' for ' || r.owner || '.' || r.object_name;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks but that's just for tables.  What would I do about Views, Procedures, Packages, etc?

Comment: Sure - I edited to add a suggestion for other object types.